# When I run react-native cause a exception I don't know how to solve

Tags: react-native

I download the react-native project from git，and `npm install node_models`, then I run react-native run-android case an exception

I tried method such as add maven { URL "https://maven.google.com" } before 
`jcenter()` but it still doesn't work

```
    repositories {
        // google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } //react-native-video
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
         maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }    // used for MPAndroidChart

         mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

```
"* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ': app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-device-info'.
      > Could not find common.jar (android.arch.core:common:1.0.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/common/1.0.0/common-1.0.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output."
```

Comment: `react-native-device-info` package is not linked ... run `react-native link react-native-device-info` in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

then I tried to write code like this ,it works

```
allprojects { 
    repositories {
         maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } 
         maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } 
         mavenLocal() 
        //  google()
         jcenter() 
         maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" }  
    } 
}
```

so, why have to write like this confues me.